# how to restrict IPs in SVN in linux?

Tags: linux, apache, svn

I want to restrict specific IP address in SVN repository in Linux. Can I done through SVN configurations or do i need to restrict in Apache configuration. if so how ?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if you want to restrict SVN to be accessed only from some IP, or restrict certain IP from accessing SVN setup of yours, it is done with iptables command.

Comment: could you please mention the exact way of doing it.

Comment: Sure, in case you want to block IP (blacklist) `iptables -A INPUT -s [IP] -j DROP` or in case you want to white-list, you first set the default policy to DROP, then white-list only the interesting IP `iptables -P INPUT DROP ; iptables -A INPUT -s [ip] -j ACCEPT` - this all depends on what security policy one would like to start implementing.